# numpy array indexing says out of range

Tags: python, numpy

I think I am doing something wrong in the last line of the code for array indexing. I want the output for p to be like this-

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [44,  0,  0],
       [45, 55,  0],
       [46, 56,  0],
       [47, 57,  0],
       [48, 58,  0],
       [39, 49, 59],
       [40, 50, 60]])
```

Here is the code-

```
import numpy as np
dx = 8
dy = 10
bx = 5.34
by = 1.09
index = np.zeros((dx+dy),dtype = 'int32')
for i in np.arange(1,dy+1):
    for j in np.arange (1,dx+1):
        if i-by > 0:
            theta = 180*np.arctan(abs(j-bx)/(i-by))/np.pi
            if theta<10:
                r = np.around(np.sqrt((j-bx)**2+(i-by)**2))                
                if r>0:
                    index[r]+=1                 
                    p = np.zeros((r,index[r]),dtype = 'int32')
                    p[r,index[r]] = i+(j-1)*dy
```

Can someone please point me out what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm not exactly sure how you intend to get your output from that code (perhaps you could further explain what your trying to), the problem with the last line of your code is simple.

You make an array with shape (r, index[r]), however remember that indices start with 0. Therefore change the last line to

```
p[r-1, index[r]-1] = i+(j-1)*dy
```

Comment: well, there are 9 r values and 9 index[r] values. The first pair is (3,1), the second pair is (4,1), third (4,2) and so on. These pair should be used as indices for p and the corresponding value of i+(j-1)*dy should be positioned in the p array which will finally give the output mentioned in the post

Answer (score 1):

After running the code, you can see what the objects are in the interpreter:

```
>>> p
array([[0],
       [0],
       [0]])

>>> (r, index[r])
(3.0, 1)

>>> p[3.0, 1]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#27>", line 1, in <module>
    p[3.0, 1]
IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

From this information, you can see that the variables are assigned in such a way that there will be an exception caused by the array access p[r,index[r]]. So perhaps you wanted to append your value to the array rather than assigning to a location that doesn't exist.